# Extract lines from a large file that do not end with "H" into another file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that looks like the following:

```
TITLE     Protein in water t=   0.00000
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
ATOM      1  N   SER A 107      20.799  63.728  25.985  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  H1  SER A 107      21.658  64.259  25.980  1.00  0.00           H
```

This is a very large file: `1.6G` and a little over 20 million lines. I would like to get the lines that do not start with `ATOM` *and* end with `H` and save them into another file. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `grep -v H$ very_large_file >results`, or `sed '/H$/d' very_large_file >results`.

Comment: How do you measure efficiency? Time it takes to enter the command? Execute the command? Remember how it works 2 years from now?

Comment: What if a "REMARK" line - or the TITLE line - ends with "H" ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller There is no such line in my file, but that is a valid concern. To make it more general, maybe we can search lines that start with ATOM and end with H?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I just need something that will be done in a few minutes. It seems to run fairly quickly.

Comment: Since this is a PDB file it has fixed column (Fortran) assignments, so a rather 'efficient' equivalent approach would be (that's nine dots):   grep -v '^ATOM.........H' myfile.pdb > hydrogen_suppressed_file.pdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the clarification from the comments,

```
sed -n '/^ATOM.*H$/!p' input > output
```

will remove (not print) lines that start with "ATOM" and end with "H" from the file named `input` and print the rest of the lines into the file named `output`. The sed syntax goes, from left to right:

- `-n` -- don't print lines by default
- `/^ATOM.*H$/` -- look for lines that start with ATOM, followed by any number of characters, ending (`$`) with H
- `!p` -- print lines that *don't* match the above pattern

A sample input file of:

```
TITLE     Protein in water t=   0.00000
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
ATOM      1  N   SER A 107      20.799  63.728  25.985  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  H1  SER A 107      21.658  64.259  25.980  1.00  0.00           H
TITLE     Protein in water t=   0.00000H
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOXH
ATOM      1  N   SER A 107      20.799  63.728  25.985  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  H1  SER A 107      21.658  64.259  25.980  1.00  0.00           H
```

results in:

```
TITLE     Protein in water t=   0.00000
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOX
ATOM      1  N   SER A 107      20.799  63.728  25.985  1.00  0.00           N
TITLE     Protein in water t=   0.00000H
REMARK    THIS IS A SIMULATION BOXH
ATOM      1  N   SER A 107      20.799  63.728  25.985  1.00  0.00           N
```

A more direct sed syntax would be:

```
sed '/^ATOM.*H$/d' input > output
```

which says:

- (print lines by default)
- search for lines that start with ATOM and end with H
- delete (don't print) those lines

Comment: or with grep: `grep -v '^ATOM.*H$' input > output`. grep prints matching lines, and `-v` inverts the match. Of course the latter `sed` in this answer is more efficient by one character. :)

Comment: @ikkachu, `grep -xv ATOM.\*H` wins.

Answer (score 2):

The tool to select lines based on their content is [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), as long as the rule to select the content can be expressed as a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

A regular expression for “starts with `ATOM`” is `^ATOM`. A regular expression for “ends with `H`” is `H$`. Since the two can't overlap, a regular expression for “starts with `ATOM`, then contains anything, and ends with `H`” is `^ATOM.*H$`.

To select lines that do not match the regular expression, use the `-v` option.

```
grep -v '^ATOM.*H$' large_file.txt >not_atom_h.txt
```

For more general conditions, especially for a column-based format, you can use [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Here is an awk program that's equivalent for your sample data: it prints lines where the first column is not `ATOM`, or the last column is not `H`. In this specific case, there is no advantage to awk, it would be slower and not simpler. I mention it because small variations on your problem, for example if a column was added after the one that may or may not be `H`, would make it a lot more difficult to solve with grep.

```
awk '$1 != "ATOM" || $NF != "H"' large_file.txt >not_atom_h.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of length of the command line, the shortest I can think of is:

```
grep -vx ATOM.\*H
```

In terms of processing speed, on my system at least, the quickest I've found was:

```
mawk '!/^ATOM.*H$/'
```

Answer (score -3):

(NOT THE BEST SOLUTION, per comments below)

You could also do:

grep '[H$]' source-file > target-file

Placing "H$" (which means "ends with H") within square brackets negates it. So grep will flag entries that dont match "H$"

Comment: Could you explain how this works?

Comment: Edited my entry

Comment: In what version of `grep` does placing characters inside square brackets indicate regex negation? It looks to me like your expression prints any lines that contain either `H` or (literal) `$`

Comment: Um, no, the brackets will match any character listed (and like most others, `$` has no special meaning inside a [bracket expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)), and because there's no anchor, the whole pattern will match any line with an `H` or a `$` anywhere. OTOH `[^H]$` would match anything _except_ an `H` just before end-of-line, and `grep -v 'H$'` would match any lines that don't end in an`H`;

Comment: If I was to guess, you saw this sort of grep syntax while trying to look for a specific process while *also* trying to omit the grep process. The behavior is distinct from the meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the critiques everyone. I've updated my response to indicate that its not ideal. Thanks again.